# Does localstorage clear after app store update on react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I wonder that clearing localstorage when app is updated on app store.I mean if we uninstall app and then app reinstall ,local storage was cleared.I am not sure about that clearing local storage when app is updated.
I didn't find out any information about subject.Have you any idea about issue?

If local storage does not clear when app is updated on app store ,How should we make for clearing local storage ? 
By the way we are using react native as framework.I mean if you any suggestions about subject, it should be according to react native.

Comment: No, local storage (I assume you're talking about AsyncStorage) doesn't clear on an update, and generally you wouldn't want it to so your user has persistence through the process. If you need to, though, you could use your version string as a flag and do multiRemove on your values.

Comment: Local storage does not get clears on App update. Only possible issue is with coredata (if using), you have to apply coredata migration. If no coredata then relax, app update would not effect

Answer (score 0):

The local storage won't be cleared by updating your app. If you want to clear the old datas, you can use [AsyncStorage.multiRemove](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#multiremove) function.